# Streamsets solrcloud on CDH 5.7 unable to connect to Solr

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera-cdh, solrcloud, streamsets

I am using streamsets on CDH version 5.7.0

A sample workflow to load a file from HDFS(origin) and create records on Solr (destination). It is failing on validation - SOLR_03 - Could not connect to the Solr instance: org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZooKeeperException: : ZooKeeper Connection String.

However, from the logs, I see that it is able to connect to zookeeper, but, somehow closes the session after calling the /live_nodes zookeeper api.

```
2016-06-03 16:30:21,336 INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager: Client is connected to ZooKeeper

2016-06-03 16:30:21,336 INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient: Using default ZkACLProvider

2016-06-03 16:30:21,338 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x355187691370039, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 1,3  replyHeader:: 1,42949673777,0  request:: '/clusterstate.json,F  response:: s{38654846788,38654846788,1464989414801,1464989414801,0,0,0,0,0,0,38654846788} 

2016-06-03 16:30:21,339 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x355187691370039, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 2,3  replyHeader:: 2,42949673777,0  request:: '/aliases.json,F  response:: s{38654846789,38654846789,1464989414814,1464989414814,0,0,0,0,0,0,38654846789} 

2016-06-03 16:30:21,339 INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader: Updating cluster state from ZooKeeper... 

2016-06-03 16:30:21,339 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x355187691370039, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 3,3  replyHeader:: 3,42949673777,0  request:: '/clusterstate.json,T  response:: s{38654846788,38654846788,1464989414801,1464989414801,0,0,0,0,0,0,38654846788} 

2016-06-03 16:30:21,340 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x355187691370039, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 4,8  replyHeader:: 4,42949673777,-101  request:: '/live_nodes,T  response:: v{} 

2016-06-03 16:30:21,340 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Closing session: 0x355187691370039

2016-06-03 16:30:21,340 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Closing client for session: 0x355187691370039

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x355187691370039, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,-11  replyHeader:: 5,42949673778,0  request:: null response:: null

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Disconnecting client for session: 0x355187691370039

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x355187691370039 closed

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 INFO com.streamsets.pipeline.cluster.ControlChannel: Producer complete

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 DEBUG com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask: Returning private ClassLoader for 'streamsets-datacollector-cdh_5_7-lib'

2016-06-03 16:30:21,352 DEBUG com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask: Returned a private ClassLoader for 'streamsets-datacollector-cdh_5_7-lib', active private ClassLoaders='0'

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection manager is shutting down

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection manager shut down

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.manager.standalone.StandaloneAndClusterPipelineManager: Status of previewer with id: '0bec83af-c152-4519-98f4-201394bebc36' changed to status: 'INVALID'

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 INFO com.streamsets.pipeline.cluster.ControlChannel: Producer complete

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask: Returning private ClassLoader for 'streamsets-datacollector-cdh_5_7-lib'

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 WARN com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask: Could not return a private ClassLoader for 'streamsets-datacollector-cdh_5_7-lib', active private ClassLoaders='0'

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 WARN com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline: Exception thrown during pipe 'StagePipe[instance='com_streamsets_pipeline_stage_origin_hdfs_cluster_ClusterHdfsDSource_01' input='[]' output='[com_streamsets_pipeline_stage_origin_hdfs_cluster_ClusterHdfsDSource_01OutputLane14649766295360::s]']' destroy: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object has already been returned to this pool or is invalid

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object has already been returned to this pool or is invalid

at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.releaseStageClassLoader(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:448)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewStageLibraryTask.releaseStageClassLoader(PreviewStageLibraryTask.java:92)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.creation.StageBean.releaseClassLoader(StageBean.java:60)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.destroy(StageRuntime.java:203)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.destroy(StagePipe.java:275)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.Pipeline.destroy(Pipeline.java:187)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipeline.destroy(PreviewPipeline.java:71)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.sync.SyncPreviewer.start(SyncPreviewer.java:205)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.execution.preview.async.AsyncPreviewer$2.call(AsyncPreviewer.java:96)

at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:233)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)

at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)

at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object has already been returned to this pool or is invalid

at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.returnObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:484)

at com.streamsets.datacollector.stagelibrary.ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.releaseStageClassLoader(ClassLoaderStageLibraryTask.java:442)

... 15 more

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection manager is shutting down

2016-06-03 16:30:21,353 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection manager shut down
```

So, to verify, I connected to zookeeper and queried the live_nodes:

```
[root@hadoop3 ~]# zookeeper-client

Connecting to localhost:2181

Welcome to ZooKeeper!

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 5] ls /solr

[configs, overseer, aliases.json, live_nodes, collections, overseer_elect, clusterstate.json, solr.xml, zkdtsm, clusterprops.json, token]

[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 6] ls /solr/live_nodes

[hadoop3:8983_solr, hadoop4:8983_solr, hadoop2:8983_solr, hadoop5:8983_solr]
```

Not sure, why the response is empty when streamsets calls the API and why it complains about "Zookeeper Connection String" when it is able to connect... Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Add `/solr` to your ZooKeeper URL, so it looks like : `host:port/solr`.

Comment: Had the exact same problem as described in the question. Adding "/solar" worked for me.